# selenium webdriver how to select from list menu item

Tags: select, selenium, menu, webdriver

How do I select an item in the list of menu items once it appears as a dropdown? I tried sendKeys to input the text like "Brown Mustard", but it clears out when I hit the submit button. I know I should be able to type it in the field but WebDriver sendKeys didn't work, so if you have suggestions on how to select from a list menuitems, thanks so much!

Here's the html snippet of the text field and the menu items that appear when you enter say "B"

```
     <input id="combobox0-text" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget 
     ui-widget-content tableRightFormTextField" autocomplete="off" 
     role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"> 

    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" 
    tabindex="-1">Bro<strong>w</strong>n Mustard</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all"    
    tabindex="-1">Bro<strong>w</strong>ntop</a></li>
```

Comment: what happens when you simply input "b" using webdriver.sendKeys() into your input field?

Comment: The dropdown you are referring to is not a simple combobox. You need to perform click operation for the drop down values to displayed. Also you cannot simply use sendkeys method to enter the text. Have answered a similar question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181435/not-able-to-select-element-from-drop-down-list/18201310#18201310>. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using wait,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("combobox0-text"))).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("combobox0-text")).sendKeys("Brown Mustard");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.ui-menu-item"))).click();
```

the above code will clear the `input field` and `type in the required item` and wait for the menu item to appear in the drop down...,the 3rd statement will click on the `menu item`..

Answer (score 1):

This is how it shall work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("combobox0-text")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("combobox0-text")).SendKeys("bro");
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.ui-menu-item")).Click();
```

FYI: It shall select the first/top menu item after sending keys. So, type more keys if you wanted to select a particular item.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but it throws an error, element not clickable at this moment.

Comment: Try downloading the latest firefox and selenium. If its public website than pleaseprovide the link.

Answer (score 1):

After entering B, you could create a select object of the menu items and then select items based on  visible text

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


//your code before entering B
Select menu = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("combobox0-text")));
menu.selectByVisibleText("Brown Mustard");
```

Comment: This does only work with selections using the <select> Element since selenium checks if the WebElement passed to the constructor of Select is actually a <Select> element.