# Not able to select element from drop down list

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem that i am not able to select element from drop down list to proceed further.

The URL for reference site is "http://www.rechargeitnow.com/needrecharge.jspx"

I tried the code below but didn't got success.

```java
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
//WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("opId_div")));
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='operatorid']")).sendKeys("Airtel");;

//driver.findElement(By.linkText("mobile")).sendKeys("Airtel");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oprauto']")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/select/option[5]")).findElement(By.name("Airtel"));
//operator.selectByIndex(1);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oprauto']")).sendKeys("Airtel");


driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[3]/ul/li[3]/img")).click(); 
//Select operator=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("operatorid")));
//operator.getOptions();
//operator.selectByVisibleText("Airtel");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("                     mobile no.              ")).sendKeys("9001785845");

driver.findElement(By.id("transSubscriptionNoID")).sendKeys("9001457868");
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[id='btn']")).submit();
//driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn']"));
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you tried (your code)?

Comment: The site you have mentioned does not contain simple select drop down rather an ajax drop down where based upon what you type the options get loaded dynamically. There is a way to handle this. Before that can you please share your code?

Comment: @vinay as i said that i am new to web driver so can u pls give me the code for this, so that i can try further

Comment: Ok, I looked at the page...it is not a standard dropdown.  However, instead of the `Select` code, you can click on the arrow (That opens the dropdown), and then select the option using By.linkText("Airtel").

Comment: @MrTi  T tried this one also but it's not working........

Comment: @MrTi Please verify before posting an answer.

Comment: Comment != answer.  I was simply mentioning a possibility, not what will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Java but I was able to easily accomplish this in Ruby with the following code.

```
$driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='input_dropdown']/div[1]/img").click
$driver.find_element(:link, "T24").click
```

You can replace "T24" with any of the other options available on the dropdown. 
Hopefully this answers half of your question at least and someone will be able to translate this into Java.

Answer (score 0):

So the combo drop down is not a select box, its an unordered list, wrapped around an input. You would need to click on the drop down icon and then click the element you want. Here is some dirty code that WORKS :). It selects "Idea" from the drop down.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.rechargeitnow.com/needrecharge.jspx");
WebElement dropDownArrow = driver.findElement(By
                    .id("input_dropdown"));
dropDownArrow.click();
WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Idea")));
option.click();
```

Comment: this code took me to the service page of idea... but i want to proceed to recharge with idea.....

Comment: That was not the original question. The original question asked how to select drop down from the list, my solution provides that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. This is not what I wanted to provide you with as a code. But works none the less. You can replace Airtel with any other text present in the drop down.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("oprauto")).sendKeys("Airtel");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li/a/strong[text() = 'Airtel']")).click();
```